# Python C-API: Signal handling, specifically SIGABRT

Tags: python-c-api

Some python functions can raise the SIGABRT signal via os.abort(). I am currently embedding a python interpreter in my C++ code but I don't want the execution to crash when this happens.

I tried it with a classical signal handling:

```
#include <signal.h>
void myhandler(int sig) 
{ 
    std::cout<< "Signal cought by C++ layer";
}
int main()
{

   signal(SIGABRT, &myhandler);
    Py_InitializeEx(skipSignalHandlerRegistration);
    PyRun_SimpleString("import os\n"
                       "os.abort()");
 ....
}
```

After raising the signal, I actually end up inside the handler. But then the abort is executed anyway. It is actually the same problem as [here](https://discuss.python.org/t/how-can-i-handle-sigabrt-from-third-party-c-code-std-abort-call/22078/4). In the post the final solution was to fork a process and let it die when the signal is raised. I wanted to bring it up here to see if anyone has an alternative solution?